# Using htaccess with Codeigniter and specific rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I can not add specific rewrite rule to .htaccess file in which codeigniter rewrite rules present.

```
              Options -Indexes
      Options +FollowSymLinks



      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
         RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system|sayfalar|main\.php)
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ /main.php?tag=$1 [L,NC]

        DirectoryIndex home.php
      </IfModule>
```

The section `RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ /main.php?tag=$1 [L,NC]` not working at all

When I type site.com/main/decoraion corresponding to main.php?tag=decoration , I got Codeigniter'S 404 error page. Codeigniter's rule handles the request though I tell htaccess not to consider main.php file when rewriting

What is the correct way for adding this rule?

Comment: _“What is the correct way for adding this rule?”_ - there probably isn’t one, because trying to match that pattern again makes rather little sense to begin with. `^(.*)$` is just _any_ path, and CI is rewriting that to the index.php itself already.

Comment: `^main/(.*)$` not working as well When I type site.com/main/decoration corresponding to main.php?tag=decoration

Comment: So _where_ did you try to add this rule then? And did you at least check what the error log has to say?

Comment: They are in the same file

Comment: . When I type site.com/main/decoration , I get Codeigniter's 404 error page . I guess Codeigniter's rewrite rule handles the request

Comment: I meant what _position_, before or after the CI stuff. Show the actual contents of your .htaccess, please, edit the question.

Comment: Ok I edited. Take a look again please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should swap the two rules :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    # => Put your specific rule here !
    RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ /main.php?tag=$1 [L,NC]

    # The remaining route, acting as a "catch-all"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # I'm not really sure the purpose of your next condition, but I suspect it's useless. See comment.
    #RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system|sayfalar|main\.php)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    DirectoryIndex home.php
</IfModule>
```

Just to remind you, [L] means that this rule should be the last one to apply if it matches.

So when you did `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`, you told Apache to match any URL and rewrite it to your index, and to not look for further rules. Hence your issue.

So the main takeaway is to rewrite to index at the end (to act like a "catch-all"), and add specific route before.

Comment: Note that I'm not really sure what you wanter to do with the condition `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system|sayfalar|main\.php)`. I you wanted to ignore files/folder, it's useless since the previous conditions `!-f` and `!-d` will do exactly this.

Comment: That's it :) Thank you . I would like to thank @04FS for his interest